# React how to render array element in alternating layout

Tags: reactjs

I have an array of objects, each having a content and an image as shown below

```js
const items = [
    {
        id: 1,
        content: "some content",
        img: "img_url"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        content: "some content",
        img: "img_url"
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        content: "some content",
        img: "img_url"
    },
]
```

I want to render this in an alternate pattern as shown below
[image]

Right now I am iterating over the array and rendering as image followed by content.

```js
<div className="row">
{items.map(item=>(
    <div className="col-6">
        <img src={item.img} />
    </div>
    <div className="col-6">
        <p>{item.content}</p>
    </div>
))}
</div>
```

How do I modify this such that I get the layout shown in the picture?

Comment: I would programaticaly try to change the flex order based on if the `id` or an array index is even or odd

Comment: You can use `flex-direction` property, and alternate it between `row` and `row-reverse`

Answer (score 1):

You can conditionally change the order of the columns:

```
<div className="row">
{items.map((item, index)=>(
    {index % 2 === 0 ? <div className="col-6">
        <img src={item.img} />
    </div>
    <div className="col-6">
        <p>{item.content}</p>
    </div> : 
    <div className="col-6">
        <p>{item.content}</p>
    </div>
    <div className="col-6">
       <img src={item.img} />
    </div>
))}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can define 2 different classes like

```html
<style>
.left {
  //some css for left
}
.right {
  //some css for right
}
</style>
```

and then do it like this

```html
<div>
{items.map((item, i)=>(
  <div key={item.id} className={`row ${i%2 ? 'left' : 'right'}`}>
    <div className="col-6">
        <img src={item.img} />
    </div>
    <div className="col-6">
        <p>{item.content}</p>
    </div>
    </div>
))}
</div>
```

so, what basically we are doing, if index of item is even, use 'left' class else use 'right'

Answer (score 1):

Something like a function that returns element based on index:

```
const renderContentOrImage = (index) => {
   if (index % 2 === 0) {
      return (
         <div className="col-6">
           <img src={item.img} />
         </div>
         <div className="col-6">
           <p>{item.content}</p>
        </div>
      );
   }
   return (
        <div className="col-6">
           <p>{item.content}</p>
        </div>
        <div className="col-6">
           <img src={item.img} />
        </div>
   );
}

<div className="row">
   {items.map((item, index) => renderContentOrImage(item, index))}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use index parameter of map function.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

```
<div>
{items.map((item, index)=>(
    <div key={item.id} className={index & 1 ? 'row' : 'row-reverse}>
       <div className="col-6">
          <img src={item.img} />
       </div>
       <div className="col-6">
          <p>{item.content}</p>
       </div>
    </div>
))}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the magic of flexbox as follows:

```
<div className="row">
{items.map((item,index)=>(
  <div className={index % 2 === 0 ? 'left-right' : 'right-left'}>
    <div className="col-6">
        <img src={item.img} />
    </div>
    <div className="col-6">
        <p>{item.content}</p>
    </div>
</div>
))}
</div>
```

and the css is

```
.left-right{

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;

}

.right-left{

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;

}
```